# Smart quotes in a MimeMessage not showing up correctly in Outlook

Tags: java, email, character-encoding, outlook, mime-message

Our application takes text from a web form and sends it via email to an appropriate user.  However, when someone copy/pastes in the infamous "smart quotes" or other special characters from Word, things get hairy.

The user types in

> he said “hello” to me—isn’t that nice?

But when the message appears in Outlook 2003, it comes out like this:

> he said hello to meisnt that nice?

The code for this was:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new MailAuthenticator());
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

//removed setting to/from addresses to simplify

msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setText(text);
msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", MailSender.class.getName());
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
Transport.send(msg);
```

After a little research, I figured this was probably a character encoding issue and attempted to move things to UTF-8. So, I updated the code thusly:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new MailAuthenticator());
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

//removed setting to/from addresses to simplify

msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", MailSender.class.getName());
msg.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
msg.addHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
Transport.send(msg);
```

This got me closer, but no cigar:

> he said Â“helloÂ” to meÂ—isnÂ’t that nice?

I can't imagine this is an uncommon problem--what have I missed?

Comment: charset is a Content-Type option, not a separate header. Otherwise, it's looking good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the page with your form also using UTF-8, or a different charset? If you don't specify the webpage charset, the format of data coming to your script is anyone's guess.

---

Edit: the charset in the message should be set like this:

```
msg.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
```

since charset is not a separate header, but an option to Content-type

Comment: Try to set the pages charset. (to UTF-8). I think it is up to explorer to convert the pasted characters. 

“test”

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you replace the nice quotes with regular prime quotes?

Comment: That's certainly an option, but if I can avoid having to create a map of "replace <character x> with <character y>" rules, I'd like to.

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the data being received from the browser is correct - dump the Unicode code points and check them against the [charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/):

```
  public static void printCodepoints(char[] s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      int codePoint = Character.isHighSurrogate(s[i]) ? Character
          .toCodePoint(s[i], s[++i])
          : s[i];
      System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(codePoint));
    }
  }
```

For example, the symbol DOUBLE LEFT QUOTATION MARK (**“**) is character U+201C.

It has been a long time since I used the mail API, but the [MimeMessage.html.setText(text, charset)](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method might be worth a look. The documentation on [setText(String)](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText(java.lang.String)) says it uses the default character set (probably windows-1252 if you're using English/Latin-1 Windows).

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, MS Office quotes are found characterset "iso-8859-1".

Comment: No, they are not.  They are in many of the MS Office code pages, some of which are fairly close "embrace and extend" versions of the corresponding ISO Latin charsets.